# Entropy solution of the Burgers' equation 2

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, entropy, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

I'm trying to construct a solution to the following problem: 
$u_{t}+uu_{x}=0\\
u(0,x)=-x \mathbb{1}_{[a,b]}$.

For the case when $0<a<b$ I try to find a shock curve starting from point $(t,x)=(0,a)$. I get the curve $s(t)=C\sqrt{t-1}$, but it's not defined when t=0.

$u_{l}=0, u_{r}=\frac{s(t)}{t-1}$, so I get Rankine-Hugenot condition $-\frac{s}{t-1} \frac{ds}{dt}=-\frac{s^2}{2(t-1)^2}$.
What am I doing wrong?

Also, for the case $a<0<b$, the area not covered by characteristics are two triangles. I wanted to define a solution on it so it's equal to the solution on all three edges, but I can't come up with a correct one, but I can if I want it to be equal to the solution to the lower and side edge, but I'm not sure if I can do that.

Comment: In the case $0<a<b$ I get $s(t) = a  \sqrt{1-t}$.

Comment: @Rigel I added my calculations. Did you get a different R-H condition?

Comment: R-H seems correct, probably you have done some error in the subsequent computation (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the case $0<a<b$.
The Rankine-Hugoniot condition for the shock curve $(t, s(t))$ starting from $(0,a)$ gives
$$
\dot{s}(t) = -\frac{1}{2(1-t)} s(t),
$$
with $s(0) = a$.
Hence we get, for $t\in [0,1)$,
$$
s(t) = a\, \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \frac{1}{1-s}\, ds\right)
= a \, \exp\left(\frac{1}{2} \log(1-t)\right) = a\, \sqrt{1-t}.
$$

Comment: Can you please tell me, in case $a<0, b=0$ (also $a=0, b>0$ and  $a<0,b>0$), is it correct that the solution doesn't exist in points after $t>=1$ where the characteristics intersect? (P.S. actually in every case where they cross in point (1,1)).

Comment: In the case $a < 0 < b$ you have two rarefaction waves (starting at time $0$ from $a$ and $b$) and a shock wave along the $t$ axis (for $t\geq 1$). In this case the entropy solution is defined for every $t\geq 0$.

Comment: How do you get the shock wave? The limits on either side are equal. For the rarefaction wave, I defined the solution on the area uncovered by characteristics with (x-a)/t on the left and (x-b)/t on the right. Then it overlaps with the characteristics starting from interval (a,b). Do you find a shock curve between these two areas?

Comment: Uhm, ok, if the limits are the same there is no shock wave (I haven't done the computation, just a picture).

Comment: Well maybe I am wrong. We haven't defined really what are u_{l} and u_{r}, just said those are value on left and right of the curve. So I took s(t)/(t-1) for the value on that field covered by characteristics from (a,b).